# $l_0$ is all sequences with finitely many non-zero terms. Show $W^\perp=\{y: <x,y>=0, x\in W\}=\{0\}$ where $W = \{x : <x,a>=0\}$.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, inner-products

Consider the inner product space $l_0$ consisting of all infinite sequences of complex numbers with only finitely many non-zero terms, with the inner product of $l^2$ (space of square summable sequences): $$<x,y>=x_1\overline y_1 +x_2\overline y_2 + ...$$ for $x = (x_1,x_2,...,x_n,...)$ and $y =(y_1,y_2,...,y_n,...)$.

Let $a=(1,\dfrac12,\dfrac1{2^2},\dfrac1{2^3},...)\in l^2$.

$1)$ Show that $W = \{x\in l_0 : <x,a>=0\}$ is a subspace of $l_0$. Is $W$ finite dimensional or infinite dimensional?

$2)$ Show that $W^\perp=\{y\in l_0: <x,y>=0 \text{ for all } x\in W\}=\{0=(0,0,...0,...)\}$.

---

I have shown that $W$ is a subspace of $l_0$

And I can find a linearly independent set of sequences $\{b_1,b_2,...\}
\subseteq W$ which spans the space of all sequences.

$b_1=(1,-2,0,0,.....)$

$b_2=(0,1,-2,0,0,....)$

$b_3=(0,0,1,-2,0,0,...)$

...

$b_n=(0,0,0,...,1,-2,0,0,...)$

Any sequence $(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)$ can be expressed as linear combination of $\{b_1,b_2,...\}$ hence they also span $l_0$.

Is this enough to conclude that $W$ is infinite dimensional since it is spanned by infinitely many independent elements? Or do I have to show that $\{b_1,b_2,...\}$ form orthogonal basis?

And I have no idea for part $2)$

Comment: Note that $(y_n) \in W^{\perp}$ iff $y_n = 2y_{n+1}$ for all $n$. So if only finitely many $y_j$'s are non-zero, what can you conclude?

Comment: Yes, that is enough to conclude that $W$ is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: @DanielFischer But $W\subset span(b_1,b_2,...)$ so $span(b_1,b_2,...) \ne W$. Does this matter?

Comment: You have $b_i \in W$ for all $i$. So $\operatorname{span} \{b_i\} \subset W$. Since $W$ contains an infinite linearly independent subset, it is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, I get it. But if $A=\{\text{all any infinite sequences}\}$. $span\{b_i\}=A$ since any infinite sequence can be expressed as linear combination of $\{b_i\}$. Then we get $W \subset A$. Am I making any mistakes...?

Comment: $\operatorname{span}\{b_i\}$ consists of the linear combinations of the $b_i$. Those involve only _finitely_ many $b_i$ each, so generate only sequences with finitely many nonzero terms.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yep. Any ideas for part 2?

Answer (score 1):

Let $y \in W^\perp$, then using your definition, $\forall i, <y,b_i>=0$. For example, $<y,b_1>=0,$ or $y_1 = 2y_2$. By induction, it is easy to prove that $y_1  = 2^{n-1} y_n$. But $y$ has finitely many non-zero terms. Therefore, necessarily, $y_1 = 0$ and finally $y = 0.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If the only perpendicular vector of a subspace $W$ of an inner product space $X$ is {$0$} then $W=X$ or $W$ is dense in $X$.

Comment: Do you mean that if $W=l_0$, then $W^\perp = \{0\}$?

Comment: Yes,or if $W$ is dense in $X$ then $\overline W=X$